# Streets/roads without any walk-related tags in OSMnx walk network

Tags: osmnx

I downloaded an OSM walk network model from OSMnx:

```
Walk= ox.graph_from_place('Levanger, Norway', network_type='walk')
```

There are several instance where streets have no walk-related tag. See screenshot for an example. This road with OSMID

```
[27948819, 209178798, 423429183]
```

is in fact walkable, but the network also includes primary roads, e.g.,

`[608562017, 401733956, 401725912, 401692013, 401692014, 313299608, 313299569, 401725911, 313299576]`

where no walking is allowed. Why are such streets included in the 'walk' network? Can it be due to missing or incorrect tags?

[image]

Comment: Please post the OSM ID of the way in question. What makes you say no walking is allowed? Is it tagged such that it forbids walking on OpenStreetMap? You can see the exact filter that OSMnx uses [here](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/v1.8.1/osmnx/_overpass.py#L58-L68): the "walk" filter ignores ways tagged foot=no. If this filter doesn't provide what you are looking for, you can also pass in a `custom_filter` argument.

Comment: Hi Geoff, 
Thank you. I added the OSM ID as requested. 
I did not mean that walking is not allowed for the link in the screenshot. I was wondering how it is identified as walkable with the lag of any walk or footpath tag. It is a primary road with a sidewalk. 
The other road is question is a major highway with no walking infrastructure at all. I tried foot=no, but that results in just 3 links. I wonder if this is simply due to missing tags.